# How do I make my textview completely visible inside of a table layout?

Tags: android

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="17dp"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I like to go out more\n than staying home." />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="True" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="False" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

My text inside of textview seems to be limited and is getting cut off on the bottom.  What property can I alter to make it completely visible?

Comment: You might want to change the value of `android:padding` of the row, that is what limits the room for the textview. Or, just change the font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiment, wrapping the `RadioButton`s inside a `RadioGroup` seems helpful for now.

Try this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:padding="17dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="I like to go out more\nthan staying home." />
        <RadioGroup android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:text="True" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:text="False" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```